# Starting a sentence with "One question..." and then stating the question?

Tags: grammar

I am wondering about proper grammar in this case. Or if I should just avoid starting a sentence with "One question..." (my gut tells me I should).

Here are some examples:

> One question you could research is, do female birds mature more quickly than their male counterparts?

I believe it is proper to end with a question mark there, and I put the comma because I also believe that is correct grammatically. Although I feel perhaps a colon would be more suitable?

and another example:

> One question you could research, and whose answer I am particularly interested in myself, is: Do female birds mature more quickly than their male counterparts?

In this second example I am particularly interested in whether I should have a colon after "is", or if a comma (or nothing) would be better?

**So to restate my questions**: I am wondering whether the examples are correct, or if there are any suggestions/corrections regarding them. Additionally, is starting a sentence with "One question..." is okay, or should I avoid doing so for some reason?

Thanks.

**Bonus Example**: (I am okay if what follows is ignored/not answered, but I don't think it warrants an additional question so I'm asking it here).

Consider the following:

> One question you could research is: what impact does doing ten jumping jacks a day have on a person's lifespan?

vs

> One question you could research is what impact doing ten jumping jacks a day has on a person's lifespan.

I don't know if the second formulation is correct or not. If it isn't, why is it incorrect? If it is correct, why do I not need a comma or a question mark at the end? Did I reformulate the question as an indirect question? (I'm not clear on the distinction between direct and indirect question yet, sorry).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your first set of examples, either are correct. I believe It is quite reasonable construction. I think you're struggling in that the first part of the sentence sets up an indirect question:

*One question you could research is whether female birds mature faster than their male counterparts*.

As for the punctuation, this is a style issue. Either of your constructions would fit with *The Chicago Manual of Style*

In your bonus example, you are stating an indirect question so the punctuation is correct in the latter case.

*One question you could research is what impact doing ten jumping jacks a day has on lifespan.*

Still this is confused by using *what* because typically *what* is a direct question word. You're better off rewriting in this case:

*One question you could research is the impact of doing ten jumping jacks a day on lifespan.*

Comment: It seems better to retain 'what' in your last example especially when the sentence is starting with "one question". It doesn't act here as a direct question word.